# Can Thymeleaf access to Ktor session attributes?

Tags: thymeleaf, ktor

In an application that uses *Ktor* and *Thymeleaf* I cannot access the session attributes using `${session}`. *Thymeleaf* [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#web-context-namespaces-for-requestsession-attributes-etc.).

Is it possible to access the *Ktor* session attributes from the *Thymeleaf* templates?

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, Ktor uses Thymeleaf's basic, non-web implementation of [IContext](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.1.RELEASE/index.html?org/thymeleaf/context/IContext.html), therefore you cannot get session attributes inside a template without explicitly passing them as variables for it.

I've created a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-1469) in the Ktor issue tracker to address this problem.